# Laravel not working in terminal

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I had laravel all set up on my computer and everything was working great, then they released version 5.5 and things didn't work for me anymore. When I type laravel in my terminal I get:

> PHP Warning:  require(/Users/logan/.composer/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/logan/.composer/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
>
> Warning: require(/Users/logan/.composer/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/logan/.composer/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/Users/logan/.composer/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:') in /Users/logan/.composer/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

Comment: error messages seem clear.

Comment: run `composer dump-autoload` and `composer update`

Comment: Ok I'm sorry I should have specified that I don't have a laravel install I am trying to make one using "laravel new example", therefore the commands you gave me return:  Composer could not find a composer.json file in /Users/logan
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

Comment: When I run the laravel installer command it gives me the same error as the first one I gave.

Comment: run composer update

Comment: Ok I ran "composer selfupdate" and composer updated but when I run "composer update" it gives me:    iMac% composer update
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /Users/logan
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section